# Scala Slick Execution error on select query

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, slick-3.0

I am doing a simple select query to the database for a login system. I am supposed to get a record from the database and then compare passwords but I am struggling getting that part to work mainly on getting the select query to return what I need. This is what I have

```
 def example() = Action.async {

    val myquery=sql"""SELECT password,id,email from profiles where email=hetmam@yahoo.com""".as[(String,Int,String)]


    dbcall.run(myquery.map { Result =>

      Result.headOption match {
        case d: (String, Int,String) =>
          if (BCrypt.checkpw("mypassword", d._1)) {
            Ok("it worked")
          }
          else
            Ok("No match")

        case None => Ok("Empty")
      }
    }

  }
```

This code works but it is not returning back in the correct format, it is giving me an error stating:

**[MatchError: Some(($2a$12$HoNBl1DBlH.X,32,hetmam@yahoo.com)) (of class scala.Some)]**

Notice above that is the correct values that I want, however I want to strictly get the first column: password which I thought I did here...

```
BCrypt.checkpw("mypassword", d._1)
```

However I just keep getting a match exception error on *Result.headOption match*, isn't d._1 suppose to only give the `password column value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Result.headOption` is returning an `Option[(String, Int, String)]`, but you're matching on `(String, Int, String)`. You could try something like this, instead:

```
 Result.headOption match {
    case Some((password, _, _)) =>
      if (BCrypt.checkpw("mypassword", password)) {
        Ok("it worked")
      } else {
        Ok("No match")
      }

    case None => Ok("Empty")
  }
}
```

In `case Some((password, _, _))`, we call the first member of the tuple `password`, and we use the wildcard `_` to essentially ignore the second and third members of the tuple. Then, on the right hand side, we can refer to `password` instead of `d._1`.

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot just implemented that and it is working